# Access value after it has been borrowed

Tags: rust

I have the following function. It is given a file. It should return a random line from the file as a string.

```rust
fn get_word(word_list: File) -> String {
    let reader = BufReader::new(word_list);

    let lines = reader.lines();
    let word_count = lines.count();

    let y: usize = thread_rng().gen_range(0, word_count - 1);
    

    let element = lines.nth(y);
    match element {

        Some(x) => println!("Result: {}", x.unwrap()),

        None => println!("Error with nth"),
    }

    let word = String::new(""); // Once the error is gone. I would create the string.
    return word;
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
93  |     let lines = reader.lines();
    |         ----- move occurs because `lines` has type `std::io::Lines<BufReader<File>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
94  |     let word_count = lines.count();
    |                            ------- `lines` moved due to this method call
...
99  |     let element = lines.nth(y);
    |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
    |
```

I am new to Rust and have been learning by try and error. I don't know how to access the data after I have called the `count` function. If there is another method to accomplish what I want, I would gladly welcome it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this problem I used the solution given of using `.collect::<Vec<String>>` but the whole solution needs a little more work. At least in my case.

First: `.lines` returns a **Iterator** of type `Result<std::string::String, std::io::Error>`.

Second: To access the value of this vector I have to borrow it with `&`.

Here the working function:

```rust
fn get_word(word_list: File) -> String {
    let reader = BufReader::new(word_list);

    let lines = reader.lines().collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let word_count = lines.len();

    let y: usize = thread_rng().gen_range(0, word_count - 1);

    match &lines[y] {
        Ok(x) => return x.to_string(),
        Err(_) => {
            print!("Error get_word");
            return String::new();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.count()` method **consumes** the iterator. From the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.count)

> Consumes the iterator, counting the number of iterations and returning it.
> This method will call next repeatedly until None is encountered, returning the number of times it saw Some. Note that next has to be called at least once even if the iterator does not have any elements.

In other words, it reads the file content and discards it. If you want to get the Nth line, then you have to re-read the file using another iterator instance.

If your file is small, you can save the read lines in a vector:

```rust
let lines = reader.lines().collect::<Vec<String>>();
```

Then the length of the vector is the number of lines and you can avoid re-reading the file, but if it's a large file you may end-up crashing with "out of memory" error. In that case you should re-read the file content, or use a better strategy such as indexing where the new lines are, so you can jump straight to the new line, without having to re-read a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

The value returned by `lines` is an iterator, which reads the file sequentially. To count the number of lines, the iterator is consumed: `self` is taken by value; ownership is transferred into the `count()` function. So you can't rewind and then request the `nth` line.

The easiest solution is to read all the lines into a vector:

```
    let lines = reader.lines().collect::<Vec<String>>();
    let word_count = lines.len();

    let y: usize = thread_rng().gen_range(0, word_count - 1);

    let word = lines[y].clone();
    return word;
```

Notice the `clone` call: you can't simply write `return lines[y];` because you'd be borrowing the string from the vector, but the vector is destroyed as soon as the function returns. By returning a clone of the string, this is avoided.

(`to_owned` or even `to_string` would also work. You can also avoid a copy by using `swap_remove`; I'm not sure there is a more elegant way to move one element from a vector and discard the rest.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that counting the lines and then selecting one of them requires you to either rewind the iterator and go through it twice (once to count and once to select), or to store everything in memory first (e.g. with `.collect::<Vec<_>>`). Selecting a random line from the list can however be done in a single pass by randomly choosing on each line whether to keep the currently selected line or replacing it with the latest read line:

```
fn get_word(word_list: File) -> String {
    let reader = BufReader::new(word_list);

    let lines = reader.lines();

    let mut selected = lines.next().unwrap();
    let mut count = 0;
    for l in lines {
        count += 1;
        if thread_rng().gen_range (0, count) == 0 {
            selected = l;
        }
    }

    match selected {
        Ok(x) => return x,
        Err(_) => {
            print!("Error get_word");
            return String::new();
        }
    }
}
```

Or of course the simplest way is to just use [`choose`](https://docs.rs/rand/latest/rand/seq/trait.IteratorRandom.html#method.choose):

```
fn get_word(word_list: File) -> String {
    use rand::seq::IteratorRandom;

    let reader = BufReader::new(word_list);
    match reader.lines.choose (thread_rng()) {
        Some (Ok (x)) => return x,
        _ => {
            print!("Error get_word");
            return String::new();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of your answer first @Jmb, but I didn't want to iterate over all of the lines. I guess if `count()` does that anyway there is no difference. And wouldn't `.choose()` fail if the random number is out of range?

Comment: The parameter to `choose` is not a random number, it's a random number _generator_. Internally `choose` works like my first solution. And yes `count` and `collect` iterate over all the lines and `nth` iterates over the `n` first lines in order to get at the `n`th one (this may be optimized for some iterators, but `.lines()` is not one of them).